# Does the order in the WHERE statement mattter?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I have read that the order in the WHERE statement does not matter, but I believe it might or I'm doing something wrong. I have about 50k records. I exported everything to Excel and filtered the report the same as the WHERE statement below and the totals do not match, by a lot!

```
 Select myfield2, myfield2, myacc, mydate, mydte2,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY myacc, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mydate),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM mydate) ORDER BY mydate) as RowN 
FROM mytable

WHERE prod IN (1, 22, 3, 45, 354, 951, 10)
  AND sta NOT IN ('LP','SOD')
  AND mydte2 between 'yyyy/mm/dd' and 'yyyy/mm/dd'
Qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By myacc ORDER BY mydate) = 1;
```

The query runs, but the record count is too low. I built the WHERE statement piece by piece and I noticed that the NOT IN statement is what causing the issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your business question? In QUALIFY you return only one rows per myacc, the oldest row. But in the Select list the ROW_NUMBER is based on each month, you might want to try this in QUALIFY (or use TRUNC(mydate, 'mm') instead of year/mont. And finally you don't need the `RowN` in the Select, it's always `1`).

Comment: Are there occurrences of `prod` or `sta` with value `NULL`? The result of `IN` or `NOT IN` against `NULL` is `NULL`, while you might think it to be `FALSE`.